# JSON RPC Serializing Object with SPECIFIC naming

Tags: c#, json, json-rpc, json.net

Im using NewtonSoft linq 2 json to serialize objects from classes straight to a json string

The class object I'm using is very simple :

```
public class OverviewQuery
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string Params { get; set; }

    public OverviewQuery(string sid, string smethod, string sparam)
    {
        this.id = sid;
        this.method = smethod;
        this.Params = sparam;
    }
}
```

If I serialise this, I get the Json string :

```
"{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getStockItemDetails\",\"Params\":\"0000000002\"}"
```

The Oracle server I'm connecting to (through WebAPI's) requires me to use very very specific naming,
here it should be

```
"{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getStockItemDetails\",\"Params\":[\"0000000002\"]}"
```

Is there any way NewtonSoft implemented a way to achieve this formatting ?
Without correct formatting, the only way to send the information is through hardcoding everything..

Comment: I am temporarely fixing this issue by added a databound string in between the already formatted query, partially hardcoded in other words..
"{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getStockItemDetails\",\"Params\":[\""+idref+"\"]}"
This works .. but is a very sleazy way to write code ..

Answer (score 0):

What the serialiser is doing with your class seems straightforward.

Generally JSON-RPC services will require that the `params` value in the envelope be a JSON `Array` (for indexed parameters) or an `Object` (for named parameters).

Could you just change your class such that `Params` is an `Array` of `String` ?